# Possible solutions to BigDecimal underflow error

Tags: java, bigdecimal, arithmeticexception

I am trying to use the `BigDecimal.pow(int i)` with very big base and exponents, however I'm getting an `ArithmeticException: Underflow` error.

To simply put it, the code is:

```java
BigDecimal base = BigDecimal.valueOf(2147483645.4141948);
BigDecimal product = base.pow(987654321);

System.out.println("product = " + product.toPlainString());
```

Yes, this is a Project Euler problem. However I know my numbers are correct. This is not a mathematical problem, it is purely me not understanding why `BigDecimal.pow(int i)` is giving me an `ArithmeticException: Underflow`.

I know that `BigDecimal`'s [`scale` is a 32-bit `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) but is there any way at all to bypass this and calculate such a big value? If it helps, I do plan on flooring the product and modding it by `100000000` since I only want the last 8 digits. If there is any other way I could do this mathematically, I'd like a hint.

Stack trace:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Underflow
    at java.math.BigDecimal.checkScale(BigDecimal.java:3841)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.pow(BigDecimal.java:2013)
    at test.main(test.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf(2147483645.4141948)` - no! Never construct a BigDecimal from a floating-point literal; you're already incurring a rounding error just by doing that. Construct it from a string literal: `new BigDecimal("2147483645.4141948")`.

Comment: @user2357112 `BigDecimal.valueOf()` takes `long l` as its argument, not a string literal though.

Comment: Whoops, fixed. You need the constructor, not valueOf.

Comment: @user2357112 Sadly that still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40556096/1849366

Comment: May that calculation overflow your available RAM?

Comment: Could it be that there is a solution to your Project Euler problem that does not require such huge calculations?

Comment: When `BigDecimal.pow` method is invoked `checkScale` is done. In case `scale * powValue` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or lower than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` corresponding Underflow or Overflow exception is thrown. As you have 7 digits after dot, your default scale is 7.

What could you do is: 1. set appropriate scale for base 2. invoke `pow` several times with value, which composition with `scale` won't break Integer MIN_VALUE/MAX_VALUE limits

Comment: Which Project Euler problem?

Comment: @OleV.V. As I mentioned in my question, I plan on using the `floor()` function on `2147483645.4141948 ^ 987654321` and using the last 8 digits as the solution to my Project Euler problem.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Just to be sure, you mean the last 8 digits before the decimal point?

Comment: @OleV.V. Unfortunately, no. I need the last 8 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: You said you would do modulo 100000000, which will keep the last 8 digits *before* the decimal point, and now you say those are *not* the ones you want?? Please explain.

Comment: The last 8 digits after the decimal point? So assuming the result has 6913580247 decimals (digits after the point), would it be OK to discard the first 6913580239 decimals and only keep the last 8? If so, the task is suddenly easy enough.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, it is OK to discard the other decimals as long as I have the last 8. By the way how would I only get the last 8 digits without calculating the whole thing?

Comment: @user2357112, sorry my comment is so late: The documentation of `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` says “This is generally the preferred way to convert a `double` (or `float`) into a `BigDecimal`, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a `BigDecimal`  from the result of using `Double.toString(double)` .” I also checked, in this case no rounding error is introduced (`base` has a scale of 7 and represents the number exactly).

Comment: @OleV.V.: It might be the usually preferred way to convert a double to a BigDecimal, but it's not the preferred way to write a "BigDecimal literal"; if you want to put a fixed BigDecimal into your program, it's better to use the string constructor. I will admit that I was thinking of the `new BigDecimal(someDouble)` behavior instead of the `BigDecimal.valueOf(someDouble)` behavior, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a decimal number with 6913580247 decimals ending in "11234048" (the last 8 decimals). You have 7 decimals in your base, and 987654321 * 7 equals 6913580247.

My problem is this number cannot be represented in a `BigDecimal` because it would need a scale of 6913580247, which overflows the integer that `BigDecimal` uses for its scale. I don’t know in which format you want your number instead. The following code prints out the result as

```
Result is 1.1234048e-6913580240
```

That is, like scientific notation, only with an exponent out of the normal range for scientific notation. For the modulo 100000000 I am using:

```
public static final BigDecimal moduloBase = new BigDecimal(10).pow(8); // 8 digits
```

Now I do:

```
    long noOfDecimals = 987654321L * 7L;

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("54141948"); // last 8 digits of base
    bd = bd.pow(379721);
    bd = bd.remainder(moduloBase);
    bd = bd.pow(2601);
    bd = bd.remainder(moduloBase);

    double result = bd.doubleValue() / 10_000_000.0; // print with 7 decimals
    System.out.println("Result is " + result + "e" + (-(noOfDecimals - 7)));
```

I am using the trick from Anton Dovzhenko’s answer and the fact that 987654321 is 2601 * 379721. The calculation takes some 4 seconds on my computer, this will probably vary a great deal.

Looking forward to your follow-up questions.

EDIT: The central part of the calculation can be done both with simpler code and faster using `BigInteger` instead of `BigDecimal`:

```
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("54141948");
    bi = bi.modPow(new BigInteger("987654321"), new BigInteger("100000000"));
    System.out.println("As BigInteger: " + bi);
```

(It prints `11234048` as we now know it should.)

Answer (score 1):

Computation could be broken in several parts, for example:

```
BigDecimal base = BigDecimal.valueOf(2147483645.4141948);
base = base.setScale(20, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
// 109739369 = 6455257 * 17
base = base.pow(17).setScale(20, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
base = base.pow(6455257);
```

`ArithmeticException` is thrown because `scaleValue * powValue` is outside `[Integer.MIN_VALUE; Integer.MAX_VALUE]` segment. Note, that resetting of scale after applying `pow` is necessary, because `BigDecimal` scale is recalculated every time `pow` is invoked and equal to `oldScaleValue * powValue`

Also, I assume, that getting pow value will take much time